# Mute all Slack channels except for some

Tags: slack

I have a Slack workspace with almost 200 channels. I don't care for the vast majority of them but there are a few very important ones that I need to always be following.

Currently, I see that I can either mute Slack completely, which is not an option for me since I must be notified when something is posted on the important channels.

The other option is that I can mute individual channels, but this means I will need to scroll though 196 channels and mute each one, which seems like a waste of a couple of hours.

Does anyone know of a way to **unmute** certain channels once you've muted everything?

Answer (score 3):

On the dropdown next to Channels > Edit Sidebar > Select all channels not important to you (This is tedious so if anyone has suggestions I appreciate it) > New Section

The entire new section can be muted using the dropdown menu in the sidebar next to that section's title.

Answer (score 0):

I just found some case how manage this:[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joG8w.png)

After that tick every chat you want to mute(also shift+lmb works nice) and press RMB on random chat and select mute.